# Ubuntu 16.04 ethernet interface. No IP address after cable is reconnected

Tags: ubuntu, network-interface

I have an Ubuntu (Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS) system image displaying this behavior on different hardware.

The `enp2s0` interface comes up on boot but if the network cable is disconnected and reconnected, the interface fails to get an IP address. Both `systemctl restart networking` and `dhclient enp2s0` manually bring it back to life.

This appears to be related (somehow) to the interfaces file. If `/etc/network/interfaces` is blank or commented out, the interface will come back if the cable is reconnected.

As soon as anything is put into `/etc/network/interfaces` (static or dhcp), then `enp2s0` will exhibit this behavior.

The system I am testing this on now has two network interfaces. `enp2s0` and `enp1s0`. This does NOT happen to `enp1s0`. On another system here (created from the same image), there is only an `enp2s0` interface. It consistently happens there.

I created a test script and put it into `/etc/network/if-up.d/` to send the date and interface info to a log file. On boot I see this:

```
lo Mon Jan 22 15:31:01 AEDT 2018
enp2s0 Mon Jan 22 15:31:15 AEDT 2018
--all Mon Jan 22 15:31:16 AEDT 2018
```

If the cable is reconnected on `enp2s0` it never executes. If I reconnect the cable on `enp1s0`, it works and I see it in the log.

I have tried all sorts of different combinations in `/etc/network/interfaces`. I have even recreated the file entirely, verified permissions from a vanilla machine etc. As soon as I put information in there, things go pear shaped.

My current interfaces file:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp2s0
iface enp2s0 inet dhcp

iface enp1s0 inet manual
```

It also does the same thing with a static configuration.

I think a big clue here is that my `if-up.d/test` script is not running when the cable is reconnected but only for that one interface.

Can anybody tell me what determines if this script is run or not for a particular interface?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Do you have `NetworkManager` or `ifplugd` installed? (Does `nmcli device show` output anything other than an error message? Does `/etc/default/ifplugd` exist, and if it does, what does it say?)

Which driver(s) are used for your NICs? (Run `sudo ethtool -i enp2s0; sudo ethtool -i enp1s0` and post the output. If it produces an error, run `sudo apt-get install ethtool` and try again.)

If you have no entries for an interface in `/etc/network/interfaces`, then that interface is usually in control of `NetworkManager`, which can detect the link-state and will do DHCP by default.

But if you configure that interface in `/etc/network/interfaces`, then `NetworkManager` won't touch it: then that interface is typically controlled *only* by the `ifupdown` scripts, which in their basic form won't include link detection at all. Packages like `ifupdown-extra` can add some basic link detection (i.e. *skip* bringing an interface up if it does not seem to have a link) but in general, `ifupdown` configures things once at boot and then it's done.

`ifplugd` might be the one causing your inconsistent behavior: I think some versions of it used to work with some but not all network interfaces. Some modern NICs go into a powered-off state when unconfigured: in such a state, they won't be able to detect the presence of a link. Other NICs have at least the link detection part always powered (or powered whenever a driver is loaded). The second group of NICs works fine with all versions of `ifplugd`, but I think the NICs in the first group (used to?) have trouble with it. If your `enp2s0` and `enp1s0` belong to different groups in this regard, it might explain the inconsistency.

Comment: Thank you. This has put me on the correct path. ifplugd was not installed so there was nothing managing the interface when it came back up if it was also listed in the interfaces file. I disabled network-manager (as we need to manage interfaces from the file), installed ifplugd and configured it to use that interface. It is working now. Are there any implications to what I have done for the X install that I may be unaware of?

Comment: Not really. Some GUI network configuration tools might be a bit unhappy that the NetworkManager is not available, but sounds like you wouldn't be using them anyway.